# Microsoft Word 2013 - create alphabetical list of headings with paragraph numbers after (index)

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a requirement to make an 'index' of a list of headings. (I am aware that this may not be an index in the formal sense, and that Word's index functionality may not be the best way of achieving it.)

I have some pretty specific requirements.

The headings are numbered (using styles and a multi-level list) along the lines of:

```
1.1 Hello
1.2 Test
1.2.1 Drawing
1.2.2 Writing
1.3 Apple
```

I want the index to appear like this:

```
Apple       1.3
Drawing     1.2.1
Hello       1.1
Test        1.2
Writing     1.2.2
```

So, I want to suppress the heading numbers in front of the text, and then to have the heading number (paragraph number) to appear afterwards (where a normal index would have the page number).

I would prefer to set something up that will be automatically refreshed as the headings change, but could cope with something that needs a bit of re-doing each time.

I have looked at the Index and Table of Contents tools, but have not been able to see how either of them would quite do what I want. Another answer on here suggested that you can unlink a TOC (Ctrl-Shit-F9) and then sort it, which might be a route, if I can first persuade it to move the heading numbering from the start to the end.

I am using Word 2013.